# Remove shadow frame that is on every image opened in Preview

Tags: mac, photos, preview

Anytime an image is opened in Preview on my iMac desktop computer running 14.3.1, they always have a faint shadow around both sides and the bottom, At the top is always at the minimum a thin white header with image name. The shadow is not present at the top above that header.

Can the shadow be removed?

Occasionally I desire to create a quick collage of images together by opening them in preview, position them together then do a screenshot of the collage.

The shadow becomes most unwelcome when I might desire to add more text below an image that already has text imbedded in a white text block at the bottom of the image, but the white text area does not have sufficient space below the existing text to add more text.

In this situation, the simplest way I know of to add more matching white space is to screenshot the image laid atop the white area of some other image.

But that shadow at the bottom of the top image shows in the screenshot making it impossible to add matching white space from another image.

Having used Macs since the beginning of time, I don't recall having this problem in years past.

I'm sure whoever created this faint shadow at Apple thought it would be a cute addition but I wish when unnecessary things are added to our computers in updates, if they would throw in a switch to turn each one off if unwanted, would help to return Macs to being a most desirable computer to own and use.

Instead, this shadow addition has removed a function I've used many times quickly, and now it's just one more on an endless list of annoyances they seem determined to keep adding until the only people who will buy and use their devices are folks with advanced skill at computer programming who know how to do work-arounds.

I'm clearly not one of those so I'm here hoping I explained the problem well enough for someone who is a lot brighter than I at all things computer, to let me know if the shadow can be removed in some relatively simple way.

For my old analog brain to understand how to do it, it'll need to be pretty simple!

Thanks.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot so we can see this shadow?

Comment: Are you talking about the shadow below and to the sides of each window? That's been in graphical interfaces since windows were invented, in order to establish "depth" of overlapping windows. You can remove the shadow from a screenshot image, if that's what you want.